# How do moving averages work to make predictions?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, moving-average, white-noise

A moving average model is
[image]

where $\epsilon_t$ is white noise that is $cov(\epsilon_t,\epsilon_{t-h})=0$, $var(e_t)=\sigma^2$, $E(e_t)=0$. How is it related to predict future values by averaging previous values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us take the mathematical expectation as a point forecast. Add $1$ to each time index, and you will see that $X_{t+1}$ (the future value of $X$) is a sum of weighted past errors, a constant and $\varepsilon_{t+1}$. The latter comes from the future and is not available to us, but it has an expected value of $0$, so we set it to that. Then the expected value of $X_{t+1}$ is a sum of weighted past errors and a constant. That is the forecast one step ahead into the future.

If you are asking about obtaining the fitted values of the error series $\varepsilon$, this is a byproduct of estimation of the model's coefficients $\theta$. Estimation can be done by maximum likelihood via state space representation and Kalman filtering. It cannot be done e.g. by OLS since $\varepsilon$ are not observable.

Comment: Look at to $t=1$ so it's impossible get previous observation due to its non existence, MA process must be start at $t=q+1$ where the previous observations are $x_1,...,x_q$ so the first value to MA process would be:

$x_{q+1}=\mu + \sum \theta_i\epsilon_{q+1-i}$ where $i \in {1,...,q}$ and $\epsilon_{t-i}=x_{q+1-i}-\hat{x}_{q+1-i}$ so how could i get $x_{q+1-i}$ and $\hat{x}_{q+1-i}$ since MA process is defined to $t\geq q+1$ and $q+1-i < q+1$?

Comment: @DaviAmérico, if you are asking about obtaining the fitted values of the error series $\varepsilon$, this is a byproduct of estimation of the model's coefficients $\theta$. Estimation can be done by maximum likelihood via state space representation and Kalman filtering. It cannot be done e.g. by OLS since $\varepsilon$ are not observable.

Comment: Would have you got me some paper or book to look through what you mean with "byproduct" or if you want you could explain this here.

Comment: @DaviAmérico, e.g. in linear regression $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$, we estimate the coefficients $\beta$ and then can calculate $\hat\varepsilon=y-X\hat\beta$. In a similar way, when we are estimating $\theta$ of an MA model, we get $\hat\varepsilon$ in the process. Hamilton "Time Series Analysis" textbook should have a section on estimation of MA models. There are plenty of online lecture notes too, which you may Google.

Comment: I got a notification to allow your answer as main answer but when i click on it i cant read the full notification so i dont even know at all how to do that

Comment: if you feel like add second comment as answer it was one thats got my trouble away